# Cannot import data into a notebook as a list of numbers

Tags: import

I have text file with a list of numbers separated by commas, which I would like import into a notebook to be called when the name `ratevector` is used. If I cut and paste the numbers manually everything works fine and the length of `ratevector` matches the number of entries in the text file.

```
In[1]:= ratevector = {0.6951, 0, 0.6951, 1.4425, 0, 0, 1.5222, 0.6951, 4.3295, 4.3283}
Out[1]= {0.6951, 0, 0.6951, 1.4425, 0, 0, 1.5222, 0.6951, 4.3295,4.3283}
In[2]:= Length[ratevector]
Out[2]= 10
```

However when I import the data from the text file directly using the `ReadList` or `ReadString` or `Import` commands `ratevector` prints the correct values to the screen but the list is of length 1.

```
In[3]:= ratevector2 =Import["~/ratevector_testfile.txt"]
Out[3]= {.6951, 0, 0.6951, 1.4425, 0, 0, 1.5222, 0.6951, 4.3295, 4.3283}
In[4]:= Length[ratevector2]
Out[4]= 1
```

**How can I import my data so that the 9 values are recognized?** Here is [a link](https://github.com/PrincessG/SignalNoise/blob/master/ratevector_testfile.txt) to the file I'm trying to import, https://github.com/PrincessG/SignalNoise/blob/master/ratevector_testfile.txt. I also tried importing the file as a .CSV file. Thanks for any help you can give!

```
In[1376]:= testimport = Import["~/ratevectorfilename_.csv", "CSV"]
Out[1376]= {{0.6951, "  0.6951", "  1.4425", "  0", "   0", "   1.5222", "  0.6951", "  4.3295", "  4.3283"}}
In[1377]:= Length[testimport]
Out[1377]= 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last input the import is ok and the length is 1 because you have list of depth 2

To get what you want try this:

```
testimport = Import["~/ratevectorfilename_.csv", "CSV"][[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you that helped! Is there a command I can use to investigate the dimensions of my data file? Something like the str() command in R?

Comment: yes you can use Dimensions (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html)