# Import command gives different solution to equation than cut & paste

Tags: import, probability-or-statistics

I would like to import values from a text file to run a notebook. The notebook works fine when I cut and paste in all the input values manually. [Here is a working version.](https://github.com/PrincessG/SignalNoise/blob/master/WorkingNotebook.nb) But when I import the same the values from a text file using the `Import` command I get vastly different outcomes [(i.e. this mess)](https://github.com/PrincessG/SignalNoise/blob/master/Broken_Notebook.nb).

To minimize possible errors I'm only trying to import the first of four requested input sections, so this post is only regarding the `ratevector` element. The other input values I cut & pasted by hand.

**I cannot figure out why the solutions are different when I import the `rate vector` vs. cut and pasting the `ratevector`.**

As background, the original notebook was written by Townsend et. al. 2012 and should only calculate 3 values: probability of resolution `prcortree`, probability of incorrect resolution `princtree` & the probability of a polytomy `prpolytomy` for a given dataset. Thank you for any help you can give! I hope I tagged this correctly.

Comment: how is this different from this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76807/cannot-import-data-into-a-notebook-as-a-list-of-numbers ?

Comment: I incorporated the answer from that post  (and changed how I import my data) and I still get the wrong solution after running the notebook.

Comment: Can you do `Import[filename,"Lines"]` and post the first few lines?

Comment: In[1]:= ratevector = 
Import["~/uce1_rates_SMALL.txt", "Lines"]
    Out[1]= {"0.6951, 0, 0.6951, 1.4425, 0, 0, 1.5222, 0.6951, 4.3295, 4.3283"}

Comment: Or did you want the first few lines after I evaluate the notebook? 1-0.5 Erfc[(0.707107 (-0.5+3.46945*10^-18 2.71828^(-2563.11 0.6951, 0, 0.6951, 1.4425, 0, 0, 1.5222, 0.6951, 4.3295, 4.3283)+8.13152*10^-20 2.71828^(-2520.76 0.6951, 0, 0.6951, 1.4425, 0, 0, 1.5222, 0.6951, 4.3295, 4.3283)-4.66207*10^-18 2.71828^(-2492.22 0.6951, 0, 0.6951, 1.4425, 0, 0, 1.5222, 0.6951, 4.3295, 4.3283)-

Comment: you keep using different file names, are you sure they are the same? ie is `uce1_rates_SMALL_.csv` the same file with a differnt extension? (There is no reason to change extensions for mathematica's sake by the way, supplying the type extension causes `Import` to ignore the file extension )

Comment: You're correct. My github link contains a different input file. Apologies, I have been trying out different text formats to see that helps. I'll try to keep things consistent from now on. The input file should have 10 values separated by commas. {0.6951,0,0.6951,1.4425,0,0,1.5222,0.6951,4.3295,4.3283}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might fix the garbage you are getting with `ToExpression`:

```
      ratevector = Import[file, "CSV"][[1]] // ToExpression
```

I'd consider that a bit of a hack and prefer to understand why you are getting strings in the first place though.

### edit

I think I figured out whats going on -- It seems if your file contains tabs, ie.

```
    0.6951,<tab>0,<tab>0.6951,<tab>1.4425
```

that fools the "CSV" import into thinking the items are strings.

This might do the trick:

```
    Import[filename, "Table","FieldSeparators" -> {"\t",","," "}][[1]]
```

Comment: Wow. That hack worked impressively. Not sure what's going on under the hood, but if I can get the correct computation that's good enough for me at the moment. Many thanks& cheers!